# Nuget 2.5 doesn't add project references as a depedency

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

According to http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.5,

> If the referenced project has corresponding nuspec file, e.g. there is a file called proj1.nuspec in the same directory as proj1.csproj, then this project is added as a dependency to the package, using the id and version read from the nuspec file.

When I create a solution with two projects, both of which have `*.nuspec` files with the same name as their `*.csproj` files, with a dependency from one project to the other, install NuGetPowerTools, enable package build, enable package restore, and build solution, the `*.nupkg` files are generated, but opening them with package explorer doesn't reveal the dependency.  The fallback scenario

> Otherwise, the files of the referenced project are bundled into the package. Then projects referenced by this project will be processed using the sames rules recursively.

also doesn't happen.

I'm using nuget 2.5.40416.9020 with VS 2010.  How do I enable this?

Comment: I wrote the wrong version of Visual Studio in the original question; I'm using VS2010, not 2008.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to automatically resolve and include project dependencies in a solution is new as of [NuGet 2.5](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.5#Improved_project_reference_support_for_NuGet.exe_Pack). I don't know anything about NuGetPowerTools, but from its [version history](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGetPowerTools) it seems it hasn't been update for a long time (if that is relevant here), so that would explain why this isn't working quite right.

For running plain nuget.exe from the command line however, it is just about adding [the correct option](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Pack_Command):

```
nuget.exe projectfile.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to have this functionality apply automatically when building in Visual Studio?

Comment: I've tried changing the NuGet.targets that's part of my solution, but changes to that file don't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @Don01001100: No, I do not know how to do that in a Visual Studio build. But I would guess you'd have to find some configuration file where you can add the _IncludeReferencedProjects_ option to the NuGet pack process.